# Nsdate Conversion returns Null

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to convert string to date but it returns null.

```
  NSString *offer_publishdate*=@"15/10/2013";
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:offer_publishdate];
          NSLog(@"date:%@",date);
```

Comment: please read about it in the iOS Developer Library before posting such questions [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

Comment: Why in the world do people try to use date formats that don't match the format of the date????

Comment: First i have given the right format,later i found something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way....

```
 NSString *offer_publishdate*=@"15/10/2013";
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:offer_publishdate];
```

Comment: Change your date format.

Comment: Why downvote to me? Am I give the wrong answer?

Comment: i haven't down vote you

Comment: @user2702179, i know you are not given down vote but some stupid men will not able to compete with others, so they just try to pull the  others legs.

Comment: Don't worry I upvoted for it and now ur neutral :)

Answer (score 1):

Please select the exact date formatting

```
 NSString *offer_publishdate*=@"15/10/2013";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:offer_publishdate];
      NSLog(@"date:%@",date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your date formatter from `@"yyyyMMdd` to `@"dd/MM/yyyy"`

[To learn  **Date Format Patterns** read this doc](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)